# Using Animation in Horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: android, animation

i wanted to create a picker using recyclerView like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sKfD.gif)

i was able to create the picker with RecyclerView and make it snapping using SnapHelper but i having trouble creating animation . 
can anyone tell me how to create such animation that is based on item location in recyclerView ?

Answer (score 0):

To animate the item you click in the Recycler View, you need to apply animation to the views of the recycler view list item.

This can be done by

1. Defining View.OnClickListener or View.OnTouchListener in the
   Viewholder of your recyclerview Adapter.
2. And finally, apply the necessary animation to the views in the 
   listeners.

Comment: Thank you i'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Try this for animations on recycler view

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.text.setText(items.get(position));

    // Here you apply the animation when the view is bound
    setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
}
```

And the animation method will be like

```
private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
    {
        // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
        if (position > lastPosition)
        {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you but i already tried this and it doesn't work as i want but its good for other animation . i want my animation respond to dragging not only item changing

Comment: Yeah do look for itemTouchHelper , if you find any problem, i will help you

Comment: i tried to make it work with itemTouchHelper and i couldn't get it to work. when i make my recyclerview Vertical it works but my recyclerview is vertical . i'm also using LinearSnapHelper